# How do I add client computers to a Windows SBS 2008 domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2008, windows

<strike>We have a LAN and the router is the DHCP server.</strike> We have a server with Windows SBS 2008, it has the IP address `192.168.1.2` while the router has the IP address `192.168.1.1`.

I have tried to add a client computer to the SBS domain by visiting `http://connect` from the client computer. But that page doesn't exist. I can visit `http://192.168.1.2/` then the default startpage for IIS7 is shown. I'm logged in as a local Administrator on the computer that I tries to add to the domain.

How do I add the client computer to the SBS 2008 domain?

---

**UPDATE:** I have now set the Windows SBS 2008 as DHCP Server. I can connect to `http://connect/` on an Windows XP client, but I have problem with a Windows Vista client, it can **not** connect to `http://connect/` and I have tried to renew the IP address and flush the DNS Cash with `ipconfig /flushdns` but it doesn't help.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Microsoft strongly recommends that the SBS Server act as the DHCP server.  Is there a specific reason why you're not?

Comment: @grayface: Yes, since the network existed before the server was installed today. I can try to change the DHCP server to the SBS 2008 after worktime tonight.

Comment: Seriously, do this.  With SBS 2008, don't stray from the recommendations too far (i.e. follow the checklist, use SBS Console vs. dsa.msc, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use SBS2008 as your DHCP server, as gravyface noted in his comment. Regardless though, you also need to ensure that the clients are pointed to DNS on the SBS2008 box directly. You could either modify DHCP settings on the router or (preferred) switch to using the DHCP on the server which will likely already be configured for you.

Comment: Ah, I will try that after working time tonight.

Comment: I have use SBS 2008 as DHCP Server now, but I still can't connect a Windows Vista cliet, see my update. Is there any command to see what DNS server the client is using? It is using the SBS2008 as DHCP Server now.

Comment: Problem solved. The client that couldn't connect to SBS2008 had a DNS server set manually, I changed to using the DHCP settings and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the domain name in your DHCP server as well. Otherwise, the connect URL isn't going to resolve properly.

Answer (score 1):

First, set the SBS server as the DHCP server for the clients. This isn't required but it's recommended. Make sure to set up and activate a valid scope with the appropriate options.

Second, on the workstation in question, set the "DNS suffix for this connection" field on the DNS tab of the Advanced TCP/IP properties for the NIC to the SBS domain name. Make sure the client is configured to use the SBS server for DNS. When the client tries to resolve the name "connect" it won't work unless the client appends the SBS domain name to it's query for the name "connect". I've run in to this on every SBS2008 install I've done.

Comment: Really?  I've never had to do this on the 3-4 SBS 2008 installs I've done so far.  A release/renew to get a new IP from SBS 2008 and good to go.

Comment: Well... thinking about it, if you follow Jason's advice then my advice shouldn't be neccessary.

Comment: True.  Yeah, I never really stray far from the recommended SBS configuration (even though it pains me to do it that way sometimes) because something invariably breaks down the road.